# Rails 4 Set field value from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yahoo-finance

I'm using the https://github.com/herval/yahoo-finance gem in an application. I'm trying to set inception_date field in the Security table whenever the show view loads (I'm still trying to just get my feet under me, I wouldn't mind this trigger on a button push either).
Under the Security show in the securities_controller I have the action take place.

```
Security.set_inception_date(params[@security.ticker])
```

In the model I have the following:

```
def self.set_inception_date(ticker)
yahoo_client = YahooFinance::Client.new
data = yahoo_client.historical_quotes("AAPL")
ticker.inception_date = data[0].trade_date
save(true)
end
```

I'm getting the error "undefined method 'inception_date='"

What basic concept am I missing? I even hard coded the apple ticker "AAPL" instead of trying to pass the params[@security.ticker] which is also not working.

As always, thanks in advance for your expert advice and patience with us rookies.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The call is working as verified from the logger code above and on another request that I have tried from the controller. 

I am trying to get to the point where I can set the value, in this case the inception date in the security table from the minimum value returned from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it looks like you need to pass an array of tickers, as well as fields you want returned

```
yahoo_client = YahooFinance::Client.new
data = yahoo_client.quotes(["BVSP", "NATU3.SA", "USDJPY=X"], [:ask, :bid, :last_trade_date])
```

Try this:

```
data = yahoo_client.historical_quotes(["AAPL"],[:last_trade_date])
```

**EDIT**

Based in the comments chat, you need to assign the value returned from the API to an object.

eg:

```
sec = Security.new
sec.set_inception_date(ticker)

def set_inception_date(ticker)
   yahoo_client = YahooFinance::Client.new
   data = yahoo_client.historical_quotes(["AAPL"])
   self.inception_date = data[0].trade_date
   self.save
end
```

It would probably be better to break the whole thing into 2 classes, something like.

```
sec = Security.new
sec.inception_date = YourYahooClass.get_inception_date(ticker)
sec.save


Class YourYahooClass
   def self.get_inception_date(ticker)   # class method, object not instantiated
      yahoo_client = YahooFinance::Client.new
      data = yahoo_client.historical_quotes(["AAPL"])
      return data[0].trade_date
   end
end
```

Comment: Using data = yahoo_client.historical_quotes("AAPL") pulls the values down put there the error undefined method `inception_date='  still remains

Comment: I see. Is "ticker" a hash? Maybe you want something like ticker["inception_date"] = ....

Comment: "ticker" is the value of the params getting passed down from the controller as params[@security.ticker].

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add a method or attribute to the params value. A params value is a simple string. You need to pass in an object or a hash to add an attribute to it. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think we're getting closer as I can follow this code and see how it works together to a point. I cringe at even asking such a basic question but seeing as I'm self-teaching on this, where do I park the Class YourYahooClass as you referenced above?

Initially I placed the code as an instance method in the security.rb file. Adding Class to the mix seems to give it a headache when I try adding the final "end" on. I know I'm missing something.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I also did opt to set sec as "sec = Security.find_by_ticker(ticker)" as I want to update a specific existing record instead of a new record. I'm I wrong in my thinking on this?

Comment: That will work but watch out for duplicate values. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: You can put the new class in it's own file. Perhaps a better name would be Yahoo, with a filename of yahoo.rb.